# Another word for "example"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

While referring to "similar cases" is there a word that sums it up? Can "instance" be used instead of "example"? I want to steer clear of "example," as I don't think it is the exact word for such sentences.

1. If you are looking for a certain style of painting, you will find many *examples* of such painting in that blue bag.
2. After some students were bullied at the school, she was looking for more *examples* of bullying in the school to report it to the authorities.

Comment: What's wrong with "she was looking for more [similar] cases of bullying"? In the first sentence, you can sidestep the word and just say "you will find many such paintings in that blue bag."

Comment: Yes, sure. That might work too. I just want to avoid using "example" in the constructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word ***instances*** works for your second sentence, with [the meaning of ***instance*** as follows:](http://www.wordnik.com/words/instance)

> An example that is cited to prove or invalidate a contention or illustrate a point

However, I don't think it's quite right for your first sentence.

Perhaps "***samples*** of this style" would work. With [***sample*** being defined as](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sample):

> An entity that is representative of a class; a specimen.

Comment: To elaborate:  "instances" usually applies to events or occurrences, not to physical objects.  This is why it fits well for the second example but not the first.